# Can I make a style in Microsoft Word that changes just one property of text?

Tags: ms-word

In MS Word, I copy in text that includes superscripting and other properties. I want to leave that alone and change the font color using a style. I've tried to create both paragraph and character fonts, but each changes properties besides font color. Is there a way to change only font color?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your style leave all formatting blank.  Go to the bottom of the Modify Style dialog box and you will see a dropdown for **Format**.  Click on this.  You will have to set superscript and color, this will set it as superscript and color.  Unfortunately you'll have to use this style just for the superscript text and another style for the rest of the paragraph.

The only other way to do it might be through a macro.

Comment: Yeah, having to do it for each piece is the problem. It's easier to just apply the color style and then fix the superscripts. I'm sure I could do it with a macro, which should let me change just the font color property, and I might do so if no better way.